# Why aren't hyperbolic manifolds CAT(0)?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Hyperbolic manifolds have constant sectional curvature $-1$. The two-holed torus, for example, can (I believe) be given a hyperbolic metric so that it has curvature $-1$. It should also be a complete metric space, with this metric.

It would seem as though this should make the two-holed torus with this metric a CAT(0) space (even a CAT(-1) space). However, the two-holed torus is obviously not contractible, but CAT(0) spaces are contractible.

I'm sure I'm just confused about the definitions, but I'm not sure where.

Comment: We need a simply connected condition.

Comment: You mean that it follows from the definition of CAT(0) space that it is simply connected? The definition (on wikipedia) doesn't explicitly say that CAT(0) spaces are simply connected.

Comment: Where do you find "CAT[0] space is contractible" ?

Comment: On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_space, "In a Hadamard space, any two points can be joined by a unique geodesic between them; in particular, it is contractible."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These manifolds are locally CAT(-1) (and, hence, locally CAT(0)). Note that locally CAT(k) spaces are also said to have [curvature $\le k$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAT(k)_space). To make them globally CAT(0) you need to add "complete and simply connected". ("Complete" will be automatic if your manifold is compact.)

Comment: So the definition of CAT(0) (in terms of comparison triangles) implies being simply connected? It isn't explicitly part of the definition?

Comment: @vukov: No, simple connectivity is not a part of the definition (just read the definition!). However, CAT(0) spaces are contractible (it is a relatively easy theorem).